# how to find the $\max$ module of $f(z)=(iz +3)^2$ over $|z|\leq 1$, $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how to find the maximum of the module for the function $f(z)=(iz +3)^2$ over $|z|\leq 1$, $z$ is a complex number.

I am very confuse, because the result or the way is weird.

I am using Principle of maximum modulo, $f$ is analytic  over the unitary disc (open and connect) implies that the maximum is on the boundary $|z|=1$

Next I parametrized $\gamma(t)=e^{ît}$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Therefore

$|f(e^{it})|= |(ie^{it}+3)^2|=|ie^{it}+3|^2 = e^{2it}+9:=g(t)$ but

$g'(t)=2ie^{2it}\neq 0 \quad \forall t$ then i do not have critical points.

If i try with other way, for example expressing $e^{it}= \cos t +i\sin t$ then
$|ie^{it}+3|= |(3-\sin t)+i\cos t|= \sqrt{(3-\sin t)^2+\cos^2 t}$ implies

$|f(t)|=(3-\sin t)^2 +\cos^2 t= 10 -6\sin t =0 \leftrightarrow \sin t= \frac{10}{6}$ but is not possible . Please somebody can help me or give me hints? Thanks a lot

Regards
Weymar

Comment: What does maximum mean here? After all $\{(iz+3)^2\mid\lvert z\rvert<1\}$ is a set of complex numbers, most of which are not real.

Comment: Dear José, i want to find the maximum for the module of $f$. Thank you

Comment: Then you should edit your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, is true, i will do, thank you

Comment: "$\left| \mathrm{i} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t} +3\right|^2 = \mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}t} + 9$"?  When $t = \pi/2$, this claims $4 = | {-1} + 3|^2 \overset{?}{=} -1 + 9 = 8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to maximize $$|f(t)|=(3-\sin t)^2 +\cos^2 t= 10 -6\sin t $$ and the answer is clearly $16$

Thus the maximum norm on the boundary of the unit disc is $4$

Comment: (+1) I was going to post an answer, but I'm glad I didn't, since yours is much simpler.

Comment: That should be $|f(t)|^2$ on the left side.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The OP already wrote that the maximum is attained at the boundary.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. @JoséCarlosSantos edited.

Comment: I got it, o forget to find the max for the last function in my post, like Mohammad did, thank you